# Android share to facebook fails to connect

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to add to my app share to facebook using facebook standard share. The share dialog opens correctly but then after I hit post I get an

```
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489): com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol.getErrorFromResult(NativeProtocol.java:434)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog.handleActivityResult(FacebookDialog.java:343)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.handleFacebookDialogActivityResult(UiLifecycleHelper.java:282)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(UiLifecycleHelper.java:150)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.y2apps.therealrace.RaceActivity.onActivityResult(RaceActivity.java:795)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3491)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3538)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:153)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
07-13 23:06:26.443: E/RaceActivity(11489):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
```

before it I get the following errors from facebook (during the load of the facebook share dialog)

```
07-13 22:55:32.815: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(10745): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: (#100) Param third_party_app_id must be a valid application id


07-13 22:55:34.106: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10745): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

07-13 22:55:32.555: W/fb4a(:<default>):FbObjectMapper(10745): Falling back to Jackson for [simple type, class com.facebook.apptab.state.TabTag]
```

I followed the instructions in the facebook toutorial in regards to the UiLifecycleHelper setup. My code to call the share dialog is

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(activity, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
                FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
                .setName("NAME")
                .setDescription("Description")
                .setLink("https://www.google.com")
                .setApplicationName("AppName")
                .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

I ran the facebook sample HelloFacebook and it worked (after I added the eclipse debug hash to the facebook app I created for it). I should also mention that I'm doing this without facebook signin.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you to whoever answers this... I will be going down this road soon too... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The hint was the Param third_party_app_id must be a valid application id error message that was printed when opening the dialog. The problem was that I was using app_id value for both Google and Facebook even though Facebook created a different app id when I added the app in the Facebook console. The solution was to differentiate the two id and use the Facebook id for the Facebook metadata tag in the manifest file.
I'm not sure why Facebook lets you continue with the dialog even though they know it is going to fail but...